# SQL Count Selective Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this,

[image]

and What I want is Count of Process for Respective ID,
[image]

**DDL:**

```
declare @t table (process char(3), identifyingId int)
insert into @t values
('abc',123),('abc',345),('abc',567),('abc',345),('cdf',123),('cdf',123)
```

I tried `Select Count(Process)`  and Grouping them by ID but the results are irrelevant can anyone help me out

Comment: What's the expected result if you later add another Process value, like XYZ?

Comment: Please check your example, I would say that for `345` the value of `Count(ABC)` should be `2`. Then update the question if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the *conditional* aggregation;

```
select Id,
       sum(case when Process = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) [Count(ABC)],
       sum(case when Process = 'CDF' then 1 else 0 end) [Count(CDF)]
from table t
where Process in ('ABC', 'CDF')
group by Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will chip in my solution using windowed function and `PIVOT`:

```
select identifyingId, abc [count(abc)], cdf [count(cdf)] from (
    select process, identifyingId, COUNT(*) over (partition by process, identifyingId) [cnt] from @t
) [t] pivot (
    max([cnt]) for process in (abc, cdf)
) [u]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the conditional Aggregation in little bit different way

```
select identifyingId,
     Sum (case when Process = 'ABC' then  1 else 0 end)  [Count(ABC)],
     Sum (case when Process = 'CDF' then 1 else 0 end)  [Count(CDF)]
from  @t
group by identifyingId
```